# Is there any dependency which can support MongoDB connection for ecto 3.0?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I need to make a connection with MongoDB for some data migration. All those dependencies(mongodb, mongo_ecto) which exist as of now only support ecto@2.1. When ecto changed from 2.1 to 3.0, its code changed heavily. Both these libraries are a wrapper around ecto and use deprecated methods of ecto.

Our production server is now upgraded, so we can not downgrade to ecto@2.1. I tried making a connection using old libraries, but nothing happened.

Can we modify in some way to support the newer version of ecto?

Comment: Fork the repo of your favorite driver, update it to support [tag:ecto3], provide a PR? It’s kinda open source.

Comment: Updation needs a lot of changes according to me, simply updating the mix.exs file is not working. Also, they are inactive for a while as I have posted this issue on github as well.

Comment: If you are just doing data migration, is it possible for you to just use the `mongodb` package? It is the driver that the `mongodb_ecto` package uses.

Comment: @JustinWood Initially I was not able to add authentication using mongodb, that is why I tried mongodb_ecto. But now hit and tried some ways given in documentation and now it works smoothly. Thank you